# How come the gridView Page is not inserting or updating or refreshing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

How come the gridView Page is not inserting or updating or refreshing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString()))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspUpdateDisplayHours", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    this.DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to a DetailsView or GridView? Description says GridView but code refers to DetailsView.

Answer (score 0):

Does your DetailsView1 mapped to the DetailsView1_ItemInserting method in the code front?

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1 " runat="server"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource"
      DataKeyNames="HoursId"
      OnItemInserted="DetailsView_ItemInserted"
      OnItemUpdated="DetailsView_ItemUpdated"
      OnItemInserting="DetailsView_ItemInserting"
      OnItemUpdating="DetailsView_ItemUpdating"
      >
```

Also, be careful.  There are like events: OnItemInserted, OnItemInserting and OnItemUpdated, OnItemUpdating. I'm guessing you really want OnItemInserted and OnItemUpdated.